# Linear algebra problem with parallel vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I couldn't solve this problem: 
Find a scalar value k so that vectors $\vec{m}$ and $\vec{n}$ are parallel. 
$\vec{m}$ = 2$\vec{a}$−k$\vec{b}$, 
$\vec{n}$ = 3$\vec{a}$ + $\vec{b}$, 
||$\vec{a}$|| = 5, 
||$\vec{b}$|| = 8, 
 and angle between $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ is 2π/3. 
I tried to solve by finding the cross product between the two vectors, but I got only one solution for k, and I think there should be 2 (angle between $\vec{m}$ and $\vec{n}$ is either 0 or 180). Can you help?

Comment: Cos(theta) = m\cdot n /( ||m|| ||n|| )

Comment: Can you explain in more detail? If we expand that, we would get  m\cdot n = ||m|| ||n||, but how do i go from there?

Comment: m \cdot n = ( 2a - kb ) \cdot ( 3a + b).  You can distribute the dot product across addition.  Do that and use all the info you have, and you can get it.

Comment: There is tons of extraneous information here. Since $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ are not parallel, if $\vec m = c\vec n$, then you must have $2=3c$ and $-k=c$. (Note that there is just one solution, not two.)